# Variável não guardando o valor atribuído

Tags: c++

Estou fazendo um projeto e me deparei com um problema.

```
#include "iostream"
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int per2 (void);
int per3 (void);
int per4 (void);

int main(void)
{
    per2();
    per3();
    per4();
}

per2()
{
int r2;
cout << "Coloque um número" << endl;
cin >> r2;
per3 ();
}

per3()
{
int r3;
cout << "Coloque outro número" << endl;
cin >> r3;
per4 ();
}

per4()
{
cout << r2 + r3
}
```

Porém, como `r2` e `r3` são de scope's diferentes, ao entrar no `per4` a informação é perdida e eu tenho que redefinir, existe alguma forma de eu determinar o valor de `r2` e `r3` ser prevalecido mesmo fora do scope?

Edit: Eu sei que nesse caso simplificado, seria mais simples fazer tudo dentro do mesmo scope, mas no meu caso eu estou fazendo em diferentes, esse é a pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou deixar um código bem comentado com uma solução para o seu problema, mas caso não conheça o paradigma de orientação a objetos sugiro que estude um pouco para entender tudo o que está acontecendo. O código está bem comentado, porém de nada adianta se você não souber um pouco dos fundamentos da orientação a objetos.
A orientação a objetos é muito utilizada e é uma boa prática de programação, inclusive para resolver seu problema, já que ao invés d definir variáveis globais ou coisas do tipo, você defini uma *classe* que irá tratar esse problema.

---

Ao ler o código você vai perceber que as variáveis estão privadas e possuem escopo somente dentro da classe, porém as funções são públicas. Isso significa que a função pode ser chamada fora da classe e acessar os valores das variáveis que estão dentro dela. Porém você por meio do objeto da classe não consegue acessar as variáveis de modo direto. Isso deixa o código mais organizado e seguro.

---

```
#include "iostream"
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class GuardaRespostas{ //criando uma classe

private: // criando variáveis privadas, ou seja, possuem o escopo somente dentro da classe
    int r1;
    int r2;
    int r3;

public: // funções públicas que podem ser acessadas fora do escopo da classe( inclusive dentro do main)

    GuardaRespostas(){ //Construtor da classe, é o método que será chamado automaticamente quando a classe for instanciada*
        r1=0;
        r2=0;
        r3=0;
    }

    //todas as funções da classe tem acesso às variáveis da classe

    void pergunta2(){  // colocar nomes significativos nas funções é uma boa prática para não se perder em códigos maiores
        cout << "Coloque um número" << endl;
        cin >> r2;
    }

    void pergunta3(){
        cout << "Coloque outro número" << endl;
        cin >> r3;
    }

    void pergunta4(){
        cout << "O resultado e: " << r2 + r3 << endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    GuardaRespostas *guardaRespostas = new GuardaRespostas(); //Declarando e instanciando o objeto da classe
    guardaRespostas->pergunta2(); // Como usamos ponteiro para instanciar nosso objeto da classe
    guardaRespostas->pergunta3(); // Utilizamos setas "->" para acessar funções da classe
    guardaRespostas->pergunta4();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado! Agora eu vou dar uma estudada sobre esse assunto pra saber o que eu estou fazendo.

Answer (score 2):

Darius, boa tarde!

Como você mesmo disse, o escopo das variáveis são diferentes, para persistir este valor, você teria que passar ele como parâmetro nas funções que você está utilizando OU declarar as variáveis em um escopo global.

Espero ter ajudado com sua dúvida.

Exemplo:

```
Dentro da função per2()
 ...
 per3(r2) //terminar assim

Na declaração da função per3
per3(int r2)
...
//terminar chamando a função per4 assim
per4(r2, r3)

e na função per4 começar assim
per4(int r2, int r3)
{...
```